# In Microsoft Graph, can email attachments be included in TrendingAround results?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm investigating a few things about Microsoft Graph mostly as a tech-savvy business user, but without the depth of understanding of a developer.  There's not a lot of business-level documentation on Office Graph yet.

When I read the API documentation about messages, I see that you can get a list of the attachments.  When I read definitions of TrendingAround, I see that it is an association of files being used by people with whom I interact frequently. In this context, when I say "file" I mean "driveItem"

However, I have not yet been able to find whether attachments are also driveItems, or whether there are associations between attachments and people, so that attachments could be included in files that are trending around, even if they had never been explicitly added to OneDrive.

Could someone clarify whether email attachments can be included in Files Trending Around Me?

Answer (score 0):

Today, attachments are not included in trending, but it's certainly something we'd consider.  Can I ask you to raise a suggestion on uservoice [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) to that effect please.